# Need help determining which statistical test to use on two groups of data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to do a statistical test to determine the independence of two groups of data, namely, the height of basketball player vs points per match. The problem is that I have 100 players that have different heights and different points per match ratios, so any contigency table would likely be 100 rows big which is a bit too much and excludes the chi-squared test of independence.

Is there any other way to do it or any other test? I was thinking to group the data in classes, like 10-15 points per match... but I'm not sure whether it would preserve the data.

I should be able to do this in R, as well.

Comment: You could do what you've suggested. I would look at your hypotheses first though and think about what you want. What is your research hypothesis in this case and is the null hypothesis of a test of independence the opposite of your research hypothesis?

Comment: [Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)!?!